# Change form action on select option

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to change the form action based on a selection value.

```
<form name="store" id="store" method="post" action="">
<select name="storeID">
<option value="/stores/store6.php">6</option>
<option value="/stores/store10.php">10</option>
</select>                   
</form>
```

Now I want the form action, to use the select option value. For example:

If Selection 1 is selected, use the folowing form action /stores/store6.php

Comment: `<select name="storeID" onchange="this.form.action=this.value;">`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the `onchange` event to change the form's action

```
document.getElementById('store').storeID.onchange = function() {
    var newaction = this.value;
    document.getElementById('store').action = newaction;
};
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ujv4r87v/) is a jsfiddle with the code.

Comment: @nematoth Just tried it and it seems to work fine in FF 54.

Answer (score 2):

Add to select `onchange` function

```
<select name="storeID" onchange='changeAction(this.value)'>
```

and add to javascript

```
function changeAction(val){
    document.getElementById('storeID').setAttribute('action', val);
}
```

This will change action after selected option is changed to selected option value.

Answer (score 2):

```
<form name="store" id="store" method="post" action="" id="FORM_ID" >
    <select name="storeID">
        <option value="/stores/store6.php">6</option>
        <option value="/stores/store10.php">10</option>
    </select>                   
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('storeID').onchange = function(){
    document.getElementById('FORM_ID').action = '/'+this.value;
}
</script>
```

check it out  i wish it will work ..

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your select:

> onchange="changeAction(this)"

and this to your javascript

```
changeAction = function(select){
   document.getElementById("store").action = select.value;
}
```